# Illegal group reference in spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES when deploying jHipster to AWS with Postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, jhipster

I've setup an Elastic Beanstalk instance with Tomcat and a Postgresql RDS.  Things work fine if I build and deploy locally, I don't have any issues.  If I deploy the same to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, the app won't start and I get an error in the Spring ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java file.

My configuration file:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: prod
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://arc.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/arc
        username: redacted
        password: redacted
```

Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Could not bind properties to DataSourceProperties (prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:323)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 48 more
```

And

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:857)
```

Again, this works fine if I deploy local.  I have made sure I can connect to the RDS database otherwise.

Anyone else run up against this?

Answer (score 0):

You need add name of data base:

```
datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://arc.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/arc
    name: arc
    username: redacted
    password: redacted
```